# How do I set the horizontal child panel heights in a vertical panel with jQuery enhsplitter?

Tags: jquery, splitter

I am using jQuery enhanced splitter, https://github.com/hiltonjanfield/jquery.enhsplitter, to create a div with 2 two main panels separated vertically. The left panel has two child panels separated horizontally. The 2 main panels are split 30%/70%, left/right. What I'm having trouble is setting the 2 child panels 30%/70% top/bottom. Here's the relevant markup and javascript.

```
<div id="mtvPanels">
    <div id="rfqinfoPanels">
        <div id="commentsPanel">
            [...]
        </div>
        <div id="rfqPanel">
            [...]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="attachmentsPanel">
        [...]
    </div>
</div>

$('#mtvPanels').enhsplitter({ minSize: 0, vertical: true, position: '30%' });
$('#rfqinfoPanels').enhsplitter({ vertical: false });
```

This gives me 2 vertical panels with the left panel having a horizontal spliter and 2 panels.

My 2 vertical panels appear as they should with the left panel 30% width and the right panel 70% width.

How do I set the left column child panels to 30% height for the top panel (commentsPanel) and 70% height for the bottom (rfqPanel)?